# GRIDVIEW not shoing complete text in cells in ASP.NET VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, gridview, templatefield

I am getting data from MSSQL in ASP.NET using gridview. The data is coming successfully. Only two columns that has HTML in it and have longer text is not showing properly. Each cell ends after 33 characters.
I am getting the data and putting it in LABEL.
The code is as follows inside gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="100%"
            Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" 
            AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="IDLessonLearnt" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="3"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" PageSize="25" ShowFooter="True">
            <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" 
          BackColor="#25a0da" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="14px" Height="30px"></HeaderStyle>

            <Columns>

<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="600px" HeaderText="LESSONS / ISSUES" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="LessonLearned" runat="server" Text ='<%# System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("LessonsIssues"))%>' ></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
 <ItemStyle Wrap="true" Width="600" />
 <HeaderTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtLessonLearned" runat="server" onkeyup="filter_LessonLearned(this)" CssClass="texbox_header" 
                    Width="590px" placeholder="LESSONS / ISSUES" Text="">  </asp:TextBox>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left" Width="600px" />
    </asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I am not using any programming this Gridview and Data source are in .aspx file. All the data is coming fine even html code in database is getting parsed but it is only showing 33 characters of the cell.

Is there any limitation in it? Any suggestions.

Thxn in advance

Comment: what's the data type of the HTML column in database?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the table had varchar(max) but the stored procedure i was using had the length of the columns to 200 which was developed by another developer. I changed to 9000 and now it is working.